# Visual studio 2008 debugging; breaking when values are being writen

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008

I have one problem with one really nasty bug(in 100k lines of code) and finding line in code which changes values(which shouldn't happen) in memory at certain address.

The problem is i don't know where this happens.

Any idea how could i create breakpoint or something to break a program on that line of code(which is making the change) when value on certain memory address changes?

Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under debug, create a Data breakpoint. You can then have it break once the data of the memory has been changed (but you cannot break on read access).

You have to run the code, and then enter the memory address and length to be watched (so break when the memory is set).

Comment: Ok i did it i found the culprit, only thing is the break happens in disassembly of some dll bult in debug for which i have source is there anyway i could reverse that address to a line of code?

Comment: You should have a callstack for that. Try to look at that. Aside from that you have no other pointer where it may be coming from.

Comment: I think i figured what was messing with my code thnx :) it was some stray memcpy.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a Data Breakpoint, that breaks the execution when the value at a memory location changes. I think you can set up to four such data breakpoints. Here you can find [instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for it.